# How to drag a button and drop over an image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <?php
        $query = " SELECT * FROM " .TB_OTHERS;

        $result1 = $conn->query($query);

        if($result1->num_rows >0)
        {
            while($rowquerycat = $result1->fetch_assoc())
            {
    ?> 

    <a href="test.php?id=<?php echo $rowquerycat['id']; ?> "> 
    <img style="padding-top:5%;" src="<?php echo $rowquerycat[KEY_NAME]; ?>" /></a>//display the image from database

    <?php 
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="draggable">
        <center><a class="btn" style="width: 100%;color:white;">Button</a></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to drag the button but I can't able to drop the button over an image
Help me to solve this.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Can you please check my answer, It will be helpful to understand jQuery Droppable in order to drag the button over the image. Let me know in case any queries.

Comment: @DarshanJain whats the point in adding an answer and a comment?

Comment: Might be not noticed from answer, then comment notified the op. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery droppable in order to drop the button on the image.
https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Below is the sample code for the drop element into the specific element.

```
// #droppable is your image element which you need to make as droppable.
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      //Drop method called once you placed your element over the image.
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
       //Do you activity.
      }
});
```

Comment: Its working but i have a another problem I want to set draggable function for five buttons but its working for one button

Comment: For 5 buttons, you can add particular class or multiple IDs comma seperated in order to work. @Nandy

Comment: Please accept/approve my answer @Nandy if that really help you to resolve your problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh kk .. For multiple buttons use droppable class instead of id(#).

Comment: `$('ul.sortable div.draggable').draggable({
         start: function( event, ui ) {
              $(this).addClass('my_class'); 
         }
    });`

Comment: it's not working.I have a only div draggable $('div.draggable').draggable({ start: function( event, ui ) { $(this).addClass('ative'); } }); <style> .active{ background-color:red;}</style>

Comment: @Nandy, You have added class `ative` in jquery Code. and In CSS you have defined `active` . Both are different.